# GWT FormPanel - avoid redirecting

Tags: gwt

I have a FormPanel which sends a POST Request to a server with:

```
form.setAction("http://servlet_address")
```

The problem is, after firing submit(), the formpanel redirects the page to "http://servlet_address" (where the request was sent), but this action is not desired, as the servlet just receives data. How can I avoid this redirection behaviour?

Comment: Did you add form.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a standard HTML form behavior. When you submit the form you actually send form data to server using HTTP request. "Method" attribute allows you to define where to encode form data (URL or HTTP request body). And result of form submitting (HTTP request) will be displayed in your browser.

As I understand you want to override this behavior. There are several ways to do it. All of them requires you to process form data manually and generate correct request. It means that you can not submit your form. There are 2 common patterns for GWT to communicate with server:

1. GWT-RPC ( https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC )
2. Request Factory ( https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory )

Both of them are easy to use if you have Java Server back-end. If you need to submit your data to non-java we-server than Request Factory only can be used and it is complicated task.

Answer (score -1):

See the following code it works fine without redirecting (this code work properly in an onModuleLoad() method):

```
final FormPanel formPanel = new FormPanel();
formPanel.setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
formPanel.setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);

VerticalPanel verticalPanel = new VerticalPanel();
verticalPanel.add(new Label("Username"));
TextBox userid = new TextBox();
userid.setName("username");
verticalPanel.add(userid);

verticalPanel.add(new Label("Password"));
PasswordTextBox passwd = new PasswordTextBox();
passwd.setName("pass");
verticalPanel.add(passwd);

verticalPanel.add(new Button("Submit", new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    formPanel.submit();
    }
}));

formPanel.add(verticalPanel);

formPanel.setAction("submit"); // e.g. servlet URL

// Add an event handler to the form.
formPanel.addSubmitHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitHandler() {
    public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
    // This event is fired just before the form is submitted. We can
    // take
    }
});
formPanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
    public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
    // When the form submission is successfully completed,
    // this event is fired.
    Window.alert(event.getResults());
    }
});

RootPanel.get().add(formPanel);
```

Have a nice time.